# Работа с директориями Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как просканировать все директории (всех дисков) PC с помощью Python?

Так же потом нужно упаковать это всё в list.

Comment: `os.listdir()` или `os.walk()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ **mepihindeveloper** конечно хорош, но я немного доработал, и вот готовое решение с перебором дисков и всех файлов во всех директориях,а так же запись их в файл (кодировка utf-8 играет важную роль, ведь названия файлов может быть на любом языке).

```
import os
from os.path import exists

f_list = open('list.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

def drives2():
    drive_list = []
    for drive in range(ord('A'), ord('N')):
        if exists(chr(drive) + ':'):
            drive_list.append(chr(drive))
    return drive_list

works_drives = drives2()
works_drives.reverse()

for a in works_drives:
    one_of_disks = str(a) + ':/'
    all_files = os.walk(one_of_disks)
    for i in all_files:
        f_list.write(str(i) + ' \n')

f_list.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать получить список дисков:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from os.path import exists

def drives():
    for drive in range(ord('A'), ord('N')):
        print('Диск', chr(drive), 'статус подключения:', exists(chr(drive) + ':'))

print()
drives()
print()

def drives2():
    drive_list = []
    for drive in range(ord('A'), ord('N')):
        if exists(chr(drive) + ':'):
            drive_list.append(chr(drive))
    return drive_list

print("Диски:", drives2())
```

Результат:

- Диск A статус подключения: False
- Диск B статус подключения: False
- Диск C статус подключения: True
- Диск D статус подключения: True
- Диск E статус подключения: True
- Диск F статус подключения: False
- Диск G статус подключения: False
- Диск H статус подключения: True
- Диск I статус подключения: False
- Диск J статус подключения: False
- Диск K статус подключения: False
- Диск L статус подключения: False
- Диск M статус подключения: False
- Диски: ['C', 'D', 'E', 'H']

От сюда ты точно узнаешь какие подключены. Составляешь массив по `TRUE`.
Если хочешь получить вложенные папки рекурсивно каждого диска, то делаешь цикл по дисками из кода выше и меняешь путь в `filenames` ниже:

```
import os

filenames= os.listdir (".")
result = []
for filename in filenames:
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), filename)):
        result.append(filename)

result.sort()

f= open('list.txt','w')
for index,filename in enumerate(result):
    f.write("%s. %s \n"%(index,filename))

f.close()
```

Источники:

1. Первый скрипт - [ссылка](https://jugad2.blogspot.com/2016/09/quick-and-dirty-drive-detector-in.html)
2. Второй скрипт - [ссылка](http://techs.studyhorror.com/python-listing-sub-folders-i-90)

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

cmd = "wmic logicaldisk GET name"
drives = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().split()[1:]

import os

for drive in drives:
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(drive):
        print(filenames)
        for sub_dir in dirnames:
            print(os.path.join(dirpath, sub_dir))
```